# Pillars of Eternity enchanting

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

How does enchanting weapons in Pillars of Eternity work?

*Specifically* if I have a sword, and it is enchanted to "fine", what can I enchant on it (assuming no level issues) and what is the end impact of this - ie what enchantments are left, and what is the number of anvils that are left, and what are the overall bonuses?

For example, if I can upenchant my fine sword to, say, superb, then assuming I have a fine sword and then upenchant it to superb - what is the end bonus and end anvil count on the sword?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it and you can update from fine to superb just fine. The end bonus were the ones for superb, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Each weapon has an anvil limit of 14, but it also only has three available enchantments to you (not counting unique weapons that come with special enchantments you can't alter, e.g. "Marking"): Quality, Secondary Damage, and Slaying.  Upgrading the quality from Fine to Superb would use up 4 available anvils, and the difference would be an extra +8 to accuracy and +30% damage.

A plain Fine sword is 2 anvils, +4 accuracy, +15% damage.
A plain Superb sword is 6 anvils, +12 accuracy, +45% damage.